# Best way to parse data stream containing of pairs of id and data point

Tags: java, parsing, stream, byte, pipes-filters

i am trying to write a simple pipes and filters system and I am currently parsing my input stream one byte at a time.

My data stream follows this format:

### ID (4 Bytes)    DATA (8 Bytes)    ID (4 Bytes)    DATA (8 Bytes)

Each data frame has 6 of those pairs of ids and data.

What is the best practice to parse such a stream? I want to be able to filter out the ids and some of the data, so that I will have a table of just DATA01, DATA02, etc.

How to I extract for example the first data point (long) after the first id (000, integer, for example) and then the second data point (double) after the second id (001, integer).

I hope I was able to elaborate my problem.

Thank you in advance and regards,

Philipp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is a great class for accomplishing what you are trying to do. ByteBuffer allows you to directly convert byte arrays into their corresponding primitive values. This in combination with reading into a buffer instead of one byte at a time, you will have a relatively concise and efficient solution!

*Example:*

```
    public void parseStream( InputStream is ) throws IOException 
    {
        boolean vtoggle = true; // Are we converting to long or double?
        ByteBuffer idBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 4 ); // Initialize our id buffer
        ByteBuffer valueBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( 8 ); // Initialize our value buffer

        while( true /*or some real condition*/ )
        {
            idBuffer.put( readFromInput( is, 4 ) ); // Store the id bytes
            valueBuffer.put( readFromInput( is, 8 ) ); // Store the value bytes
            int id = idBuffer.getInt(); // Convert id bytes
            if( vtoggle )
            {
                long lvalue = valueBuffer.getLong(); // Convert long bytes
                // Do something with value
            }
            else
            {
                double dvalue = valueBuffer.getDouble(); // Convert double bytes
                // Do something with value
            }
            idBuffer.clear(); // Reset id buffer
            valueBuffer.clear(); // Reset value buffer
            vtoggle = !vtoggle; // Code to alternate whether or not we are converting to long or double
        }
    }

    /**
     * Read and return a certain number of bytes from our stream
     */
    public byte[] readFromInput( InputStream is, int count ) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ count ];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        while( ( bytesRead = is.read( buffer, offset, buffer.length - offset  ) ) > 0 )
        {
            offset += bytesRead;
        }
        if( offset == buffer.length )
        {
            return buffer;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IOException( "Unexpected end to stream." );
        }
    }
```

This is obviously just a template, but hopefully it guides to towards a proper solution to you problem.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want to do! Perfect.

Comment: @Ipsider Is this what you ended up using? If so, I'd love for you to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [preon](https://github.com/preon/preon). See this [link](http://tinystruggles.com/2013/05/08/readingwithpreon.html) for a simple example.

If you don't want to use a library then DataInputStream suites well to your use case. See this [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/datainputstream.html) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell what you actually want to acheive.

My answer asumes that you need something like:

```
public Map<Integer, Double> read(InputStream stream);
```

Try something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream stream = ...;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[12];
    Map<Integer, Double> values = new HashMap<>();
    while (stream.read(buffer) == 12) { // Could it read all data?
        int id = readInt(buffer, 0);
        double value = readDouble(buffer, 4);
        values.put(id, value);
    }
// use values
}

public static double readDouble(byte[] data, int offset) {
    return Double.longBitsToDouble(readLong(data, offset));
}

public static long readLong(byte[] data, int offset) {
    // Do some bit shifting to adjust the numbers.
    return (((long) readInt(data, offset)) << 32) + readInt(data, offset + 4);
}

public static int readInt(byte[] data, int offset) {
    return (data[offset + 0] << 24) + (data[offset + 1] << 16) + (data[offset + 2] << 8) + (data[offset + 3]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want. I didn't realize how to "split" the incoming stream according to the ids. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Provide some example code, please!

---

I guess you have some `ByteArrayInputStream`? Have a look at the API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html

You can simple use the `read(...)` method for your purpose: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)

---

This way you can do something like this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream in;

byte[] id = new byte[4];
in.read(id, 0, 4);

byte[] data = new byte[8];
in.read(data, 0, 8);
```

Just put that inside a loop and you're done.

The stream is finished if the `read(...)` method returns `-1`. You can also check for errors if the `read(...)` method returns less than you expected it to return.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I will try that out.